# Managing configuration in Erlang application

Tags: configuration, erlang

I need to distribute some sort of static configuration through my application. What is the best practice to do that?

I see three options:

1. Call `application:get_env` directly whenever a module requires to get configuration value.

   - Plus: simpler than other options.
   - Minus: how to test such modules without bringing the whole application thing up?
   - Minus: how to start certain module with different configuration (if required)?
2. Pass the configuration (retrieved from `application:get_env`), to application modules during start-up.

   - Plus: modules are easier to test, you can start them with different configuration.
   - Minus: lot of boilerplate code. Changing the configuration format requires fixing several places.
3. Hold the configuration inside separate configuration process.

   - Plus: more-or-less type-safe approch. Easier to track where certain parameter is used and change those places.
   - Minus: need to bring up configuration process before running the modules.
   - Minus: how to start certain module with different configuration (if required)?

Comment: Have you thought about the implications of starting a node programmatically (using ct_slave, for instance)? Changing the .app or .config files is messy, and utilizing the "static" module approach is impractical... I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this...

Comment: I must of (or my cat) managed to vote this down by mistake, and now apparently my decision is locked... Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another approach is to transform your configuration data into an Erlang source module that makes the configuration data available through exports. Then you can change the configuration at any time in a running system by simply loading a new version of the configuration module.

Comment: Neat idea, thanks! The only concern is that for the testing purposes I will need several modules with same name, which could be confusing.

Comment: You could either use [meck](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) to create mock modules during testing (shameless self plug, I'm the author), or parameterize the module names in your code (which is really neat for testing).

Comment: What exist libraries for transform your configuration data into an Erlang source?

Comment: @Habibutsu: I don't know of any libraries or tools to do that. I meant manually transform your configuration into something that is suitable for your Erlang app.

Answer (score 11):

For static configuration in my own projects, I like option (1). I'll show you the steps I take to access a configuration parameter called `max_widgets` in an application called `factory`.

First, we'll create a module called `factory_env` which contains the following:

```
-define(APPLICATION, factory).

get_env(Key, Default) ->
    case application:get_env(?APPLICATION, Key) of
        {ok, Value} -> Value;
        undefined -> Default
    end.

set_env(Key, Value) ->
    application:set_env(?APPLICATION, Key, Value).
```

Next, in a module that needs to read `max_widgets` we'll define a macro like the following:

```
-define(MAX_WIDGETS, factory_env:get_env(max_widgets, 1000)).
```

There are a few nice things about this approach:

- Because we used `application:set_env/3` and `application:get_env/2`, we don't actually need to start the `factory` application in order to have our tests pass.
- `max_widgets` gets a default value, so our code will still work even if the parameter isn't defined.
- A second module could use a different default value for `max_widgets`.

Finally, when we are ready to deploy, we'll put a [sys.config](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html) file in our `priv` directory and load it with `-config priv/sys.config` during startup. This allows us to change configuration parameters on a per-node basis if desired. This cleanly separates configuration from code - e.g. we don't need to make another commit in order to change `max_widgets` to 500.

Comment: Hmm, I was pretty sure you cannot get_env/set_env without application being started. Thanks!

Comment: The application must be loaded, but does not need to be started.

Comment: application:get_env(?APPLICATION, Key, undefined), sorry for waking up an old post but you can use this to return a default value

Answer (score 7):

You could use a process (a gen_server maybe?) to store your configuration parameters in its state. It should expose a get/set interface. If a value hasn't been explicitly set, it should retrieve a default value.

```
-export([get/1, set/2]).

...

get(Param) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get, Param}).

...

handle_call({get, Param}, _From, State) ->
  case lookup(Param, State#state.params) of
    undefined ->
      application:get_env(...);
    Value ->
      {ok, Value}
  end.

...
```

You could then easily mockup this module in your tests. It will also be easy to update the process with some new configuration at run-time.

You could use pattern matching and tuples to associate different configuration parameters to different modules:

```
set({ModuleName, ParamName}, Value) ->
  ...

get({ModuleName, ParamName}) ->
  ...
```

Put the process under a supervision tree, so it's started before all the other processes which are going to need the configuration.

Oh, I'm glad nobody suggested [parametrized modules](http://erlang.org/workshop/2003/paper/p29-carlsson.pdf) so far :)

Comment: This should be the answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

I'd do option 1 for static configuration. You can always test by setting options via `application:set_env/3,4`. The reason you want to do this is that your tests of the application will need to run the whole application anyway at some time. And the ability to set test-specific configuration at that point is really neat.

The application controller runs by default, so it is not a problem that you need to go the application-way (you need to do that anyway too!)

Finally, if a process needs specific configuration, say so in the configuration data! You can store any Erlang-term, in particular, you can store a term which makes you able to override configuration parameters for a specific node.

For *dynamic* configuration, you are probably better off by using a `gen_server` or using the newest `gproc` features that lets you store such dynamic configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen people use a .hrl (erlang header file) where all the configuration is defined and include it at the start of any file that needs configuration.

It makes for very concise configuration lookups, and you get configuration of arbitrary complexity.

I believe you can also reload configuration at runtime by performing hot code reloading of the module. The disadvantage is that if you use configuration in several modules and reload only one of them, only that one module will get its configuration updated.

**However,** I haven't actually checked if it works like that, and I couldn't find definitive documentation on how .hrl and hot code reloading interact, so make sure to double-check this before you actually use it.